# DOM Manipulation from Component in Angular 1.5+

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have created a custom directive for dropdown. I want to show/hide UI elements when the ng-change event is fired on that dropdown.

This is the [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/QkiVht6UBFvjUXi1Fn98?p=preview) link to my code.

The 'onCarChange()' method is getting called but the UI elements are not being hidden or shown based on the selection.

I am still learning AngularJS, so if I am taking a wrong approach then kindly let me know.

HTML markup

```
<div ng-app="RedBlack">
    <select-car></select-car> <-- element directive
    <p ng-show="vm.showDataGrid">DATA GRID</p>
    <button ng-show="!vm.disableRunButton">Run Button</button>
</div>
```

AngularJS code

```
angular
    .module('RedBlack', [])
    .component('selectCar', {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'select-car.html',
      bindings: {

      },
      transclude: true,
      controller: CarsController,
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      replace: true
    })
    .controller("CarsController", CarsController);

function CarsController() {
  var vm = this;      
  vm.showDataGrid = true;
  vm.disableRunButton = true;
  vm.myCars = {
    options: [
      { id: '1', name: 'LaFerrari' },
      { id: '2', name: 'Porsche 918' },
      { id: '3', name: 'McLaren P1' }
    ],
    selectedCar: { id: '2', name: 'Porsche 918' }
  };      
  vm.onCarChange = onCarChange;

  function onCarChange() {
    console.log("Called onCarChange()");
    vm.showDataGrid = false;
    vm.disableRunButton = false;
    return true;
  }

}
```

select-car.html

```
<div>
  <select class="form-control" ng-options="option.name for option in vm.myCars.options track by option.id"
  ng-model="vm.myCars.selectedCar"
  ng-change="vm.onCarChange()">
  </select>
</div
```

Comment: You're using a component, which is Angular 1.5+; so it should share the $scope with the page controller (assuming you have one). If not, create a blank page controller with a method to retrieve showDataGrid - see if that works.

Comment: @rrd I want to use CarsController as controller since there are other methods there. I don't really understood what you mean by blank page controller? Can you make changes in my plunkr and revert.

Answer (score 1):

scope for components is always isolate. you have two options. option one is to use a directive instead. ([plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/gBPGzAPGfhJCtJ4BM8KW?p=preview))

```
angular
  .module('RedBlack.components', [])
  .directive('selectCar', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'select-car.html',
      transclude: true,
      controller: CarsController,
      controllerAs: 'vm'
    };
  });
```

If you want to use a component one option is to pass the value into it. ([plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/HS4wzEJvHgnAqTK6inxp?p=preview)) Notice it would be better to pass something like a model (e.g. car) into the component and use events for changing the dropdown, but you got the point.

1) define controller on outer scope and pass it into component

```
<html ng-app="RedBlack" ng-controller="CarsController as vm">
    ...
    <select-car parent="vm"></select-car>
    ...
</html>
```

2) bind value to isolate scope of component

```
angular
  .module('RedBlack.components', [])
  .component('selectCar', {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'select-car.html',
    bindings: { parent: "=" }, // = means two way data binding
    controllerAs: "vm"
  });
```

3) adjust template

```
<div>
  <select class="form-control" ng-options="option.name for option in vm.parent.myCars.options track by option.id"
  ng-model="vm.parent.myCars.selectedCar"
  ng-change="vm.parent.onCarChange()">
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my refactor for your code

[PLUNKER CODE](https://plnkr.co/edit/5VqnglrQ1mzCQWl884ZD?p=preview)

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="RedBlack">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="car.module.js"></script>
    <script src="selectCar.directive.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app" ng-controller='MainController as vm'>
    <h1>Hello a car!</h1>
    <select-car 
      on-car-changed='vm.carChange(car)'>
    </select-car>

    <p ng-show="!vm.showDataGrid">DATA GRID</p>

    <p>{{ vm.selected.name }}</p>

    <button ng-show="!vm.disableRunButton">Run Button</button>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

car.module.js //as main

```
angular
  .module('RedBlack.cars', [])
  .controller("MainController", MainController);

function MainController() {

  var vm = this;

  vm.showDataGrid = true;
  vm.disableRunButton = true;

  vm.carChange = carChange;

  function carChange(car) {

    console.log("Called onCarChange()");
    console.log(car)

    vm.selected = car.name
    vm.showDataGrid = false;
    vm.disableRunButton = false;
  }

}
```

component

select-car.html

```
<div>
  <select 
    class="form-control" 
    ng-options="item as item.name for item in vm.myCars track by item.id"
    ng-model="vm.selected"
    ng-change="vm.onCarChanged({car: vm.selected})">
  </select>
</div>
```

selectCar.directive.js // must become as select-car.component.js

```
  angular
    .module('RedBlack.components', [])
    .component('selectCar', {
      templateUrl: 'select-car.html',
      bindings: {
        onCarChanged: '&'
      },
      controller: [function() {
        var vm = this;

          vm.myCars = [
              { id: 1, name: 'LaFerrari' },
              { id: 2, name: 'Porsche 918' },
              { id: 3, name: 'McLaren P1' }
          ];

          vm.selected = vm.myCars[0]
      }],
      controllerAs: 'vm'
    });
```

Comment: When the DOM loads, the default value of the select drop-down in the MainController is 'undefined'. It is set only when I change the value.

Comment: Ohh, yes it's a little bug :) We can emit selected `$onInit` component
just add

vm.$onInit = function() {
   vm.selected = vm.myCars[0];
   vm.onCarChanged({car: vm.selected})
}

Answer (score 0):

The component you've created should be seen as an isolated component. Therefor the    `vm.showDataGrid` and `vm.disableRunButton` are not accessible outside the component template.

If this is desired, you can do two things:

1. Make the selection an event
2. Make the component use ngModel so it can be viewed as a form control that emits a value.

I tend to favor the second approach. See this plunkr for an implementation: https://plnkr.co/edit/RG51ADtvHuRSJDUMv6mV?p=preview

The core is in the new implementation of the CarsController:

```
function CarsController() {

}

CarsController.prototype.onCarChange = function() {
  // Because of the ng-model on the <select>, this.myCars.selectedCar is already
  // up to date.
  this.ngModel.$setViewValue(this.myCars.selectedCar);
}


CarsController.prototype.$onInit = function() {
  var vm = this;

  vm.ngModel.$render = function() {
   // This is called when the bound model value changes from external sources
    // vm.ngModel.$modelValue contains the new value, it may be a completely different
    // object, so set the selected to the one in the options
    vm.myCars.selectedCar = vm.myCars.options.find(function(item) {
      return vm.ngModel.$modelValue && item.id == vm.ngModel.$modelValue.id;
    });
  }



  vm.showDataGrid = true;
  vm.disableRunButton = true;

  vm.myCars = {
    options: [
      { id: '1', name: 'LaFerrari' },
      { id: '2', name: 'Porsche 918' },
      { id: '3', name: 'McLaren P1' }
    ],
    selectedCar: { id: '2', name: 'Porsche 918' }
  };
  // Initialize the ngModel value
  this.onCarChange();
}
```

Then you can simply use ng-model on your new component from html:

```
<select-car ng-model="selectedCar"></select-car>
```